# How to log into port 80 to enter credentials via a webbrowser control in c#?

Tags: c#

I have to use a webbrowser control which needs to log into an html page of the router  . 
I would like to  log into it but bypassing the log in pop up screen .

Please give me suggestions as to how I could achieve this via a webbrwoswer control on  a windows form.

Edit : This is what i could see in the source page after I inter the credentials . Not sure if it helps .

```
if(F.now_proto.value == "pppoe" || F.now_proto.value == "pptp" || F.now_proto.value == "l2tp" || F.now_proto.value == "heartbeat"){
        if(F.ppp_username.value == ""){
//                      alert("You must input a username!");
                        alert(errmsg.err0);
            F.ppp_username.focus();
            return false;
        }
        if(F.ppp_passwd.value == ""){
//                      alert("You must input a passwd!");
                        alert(errmsg.err6);
            F.ppp_passwd.focus();
            return false;
        }
```

Update : Solution

webBrowser1.Navigate(http://username:password@192.168.1.1)

does it .

Comment: Is the log in pop up screen part of a page served by the router, or is it a pop-up window from your browser?

Comment: Hi Damien , it is a pop-up window from the browser .

Comment: If its a pop up you need to look at the javascript source and see where its posting the username and password. Please get back to us.

Comment: I will get back soon . Thanks Cris ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://username:password@192.168.1.1

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate the browser to fill the form and click submit for you.  For instance for Craigslist I can login like this:

```
webBrowser.Document.Forms["login"].All["inputEmailHandle"].InnerText = @"username";
webBrowser.Document.Forms["login"].All["inputPassword"].InnerText = "password";
webBrowser.Document.Forms["login"].InvokeMember("submit");
```

I attach this to the PageLoaded event of the webbrowser control then check to see if I am at the proper URL. the "login" portion is the name of the form in the source of craigslist. As an example it looked like this:

```
<form id="login" action="..." method="...">
```

and "inputEmailHandle" is the username/emaailo and "inputPassword" was the password.  Then I just invoke "submit" and the form submits itself.

Comment: thanks Cris .. Since it is a  pop up browser rather than a form component , i am not able to use this method . but you have given me the idea for the other type of login :) .. thanks a lot for your input ..!!

Answer (score 1):

Authentication over port 80 would be in the open clear text, unless some encrypted authentication method is chosen.

I would assume you are not using Forms authentication, or Basic authentication, since both should only be under SSL (port 443).  This means the server is probably requesting NTLM authentication.  You can check this with [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) in the response header.  For Basic authentication over SSL there are some easier workarounds (if it is possible to have the web site change to allow https and Basic auth, that would be easiest).

The WPF WebBrowser control is a wrapper around the COM IE browser component.  And does not expose all of the guts and cruft.  You will have to dig in and provide an IOleSite container, to get IE to talk to your app and let you know about authentication handshakes.

I haven't used it yet, but there is a Web Browser wrapper at CodeProject (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/csEXWB.aspx) that looks like it does a good job.  Even if you don't use it, it will probably point you in the right direction for communicating with the COM layer under the WPF WebBrowser control.

Comment: thanks a log bigtlb as you said ... this pointed me in  the right direction :)